# Unable to implement single page application behavior using react router dom, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a UI in react with a navigation bar at the top. I want each of my pages to be displayed under this navigation bar as a single page application. To implement single page application behavior I am using react-router-dom version 5.3.2. The problem is it fails to display the "/home" page even though the endpoint shown in addressbar is correct and corresponds to the page.

My App.js is :

```
  function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
       <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login}></Route>
          <Route path="/registration" component={Registration}></Route>
          <Route path="/main" component={MainPage}></Route>
           //purposefully wrote below line as the "MainPage" with "home" as path as "MainPage" has the top navigation bar which I want to be shown all the time
          <Route path="/home" component={MainPage}></Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}`
```

Code of MainPage.js is :

```
    export default function MainPage() {
    return (
        <>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className='container-fluid'>
                    <div className='row'>
                        <div className='col'>
                            <TopNavigationBar />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='row'>
                        <div className='col'>
                            <Switch>
                                //puposefully writting below line because when the main page is displayed the home page is automatically open below the navigation bar (which it is failing to)
                                <Route path="main">
                                    <Home />
                                </Route>
                                <Route path="home">
                                    <Home />
                                </Route>
                            </Switch>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </>
    )
}
```

Navigation bar's code is i.e. TopNavigationBar.js is,

```
export default function TopNavigationBar() {
return (
    <div>
        <Navbar bg="light" variant="light">
            <Container>
                <NavbarBrand><h1><FaFacebook /></h1></NavbarBrand>
                <SearchUserComponent />
                <Nav className="me-auto">
                    // FaHome is an icon to click.
                    <HorizontalSpace size="50" /><Link to="home"><h1><FaHome /></h1></Link>
                </Nav>
            </Container>
        </Navbar>  
    </div>
)}
```

What is wrong in my logic? [image: UI of the app]

UI Looks like this

Answer (score 1):

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {Routes,Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './Pages/Home/Home';
import Navbar from './Pages/Shared/Navbar';



function App() {
  return (
    <div className='max-w-7xl mx-auto'>
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>} />
      </Routes>      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from 'react';
function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div class="navbar bg-base-100 mt-3">
     *** Your code: It will be fixed at the top.
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
     *** Your code: Home.
     *** Use the Link to navigate.
    </div>
  )
}
export default Home
```

```
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function TopNavigationBar() {
  return (
    <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Home APP</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/about">About</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/anotherToute">Another</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
}

export default TopNavigationBar;
```

You can fix it easily by using react-router v6.

```
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
```

Comment: Nice Suggestion but puting navbar in app shows it at login pge as well... which is not expected...

Comment: Then you can define Home and Login differently. Home folder; In Home.js ```<div><Navbar></Navbar><Home></Home></div>``` and In Login folder in Login.js:``` <div><Login></Login></div>```

Comment: <Route path="home">
                                    <Home />
  </Route>   does not execute... and that is where problem lies..

Comment: In App.js:```function App() {
  return (<Routes><Route path="/" element={<Home/>} /> <Route path="/navbar" element={<Navbar/>} /><Route path="/home" element={<Home/>} /></Routes>);
}```

Comment: Try it plz for react-router version 5.3.import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';  <Router><Switch> <Route exact path="/"><Home></Home></Route> ... ... ... </Switch></Router>

Answer (score 0):

Add an exact route for the home page in your **App.js** within the `<Switch>` body like:

```js
<Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
```

An example of code I had in a react project:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import './App.css';


const App = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
  </Switch>
);

export default App;
```

Also I don’t think you necessarily need your main content within the —

```js
<BrowserRouter>
```

If I’m correct?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that is not working...

Comment: What does your index.js file look like?

Comment: As the boilerplate code is... i have not added anything to index.js

Comment: Quick question: Are you trying to change/update the URL path manually?

Comment: @SharanBalakrishnan    Yes... I do that often..

Comment: @SharanBalakrishnan in my last project I used same logic, it worked fine... But now it does not work... M puzzled...

Comment: Does this issue only occurs while you navigate by changing URL manually or does it also occur while navigating through button clicks/redirections?

Comment: @SharanBalakrishnan Yes it occurs both the times manually as well as by clicking the icon!

Comment: Can you try changing the icon's href to "/login" which is "login" for now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248513/discussion-between-deepeshkumar-pakhare-and-sharan-balakrishnan).

Comment: @SharanBalakrishnan Hi... I tried changing icon's href to "/login"... you are right it does not work that is no redirection to login page..